# Programmatically render spacer_template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails spacer template that's used in between renderings of a collection. For example, it might be as simple as

```
<hr />
```

If I render a collection of users for example then after each user it will render `<hr />`. Here's how I specify the spacer template in my view.

```
render :partial => @users, :spacer_template => "users/user_separator"
```

This works fine but I was wondering if there's a way to render the spacer template by itself from within my controller. Something like `render_to_string` but specifically for just the spacer template.

I need this because I am doing an ajax request to add a user comment. Right now I can successfully render the comment with `render_to_string` but since it's not a collection the spacer template is not showing up.

Comment: why don't you just parameterize the spacer_template used? seems cleaner to me.

Comment: @bento I'm not sure what you mean. Could you give me an example?

Comment: well, something like if ajax spacer_template = "users/user_seperator_ajax" else spacer_template = "users/user_seperator" end and then :spacer_template => spacer_template in the render parameters

Comment: How about sending ajax request and hadnling it with Rails `*.js.erb` templates? Yu can still call partials with spacers and everything you need is to create .js.erb template in correspond controller action.

Comment: @bento That's not really my question. I'm trying to programmatically render the separator.

Comment: @bor1s I don't think that will work. I want to add just the most recent comment and have it fade in by itself.